# Best way to add a new key-value pair in an item of items list in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a sample Table info as -

```
items: [{
   "key1":"value1",
   "key2":"value2"
}
]
```

I have to update this like below -

```
items: [{
   "key1":"value1",
   "key2":"value2",
   "key3": [{"subkey1":"value1"}, {"subkey2:"value2"}]
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Update API with SET operator.

In the below example, `categoryList` has the `key3` value mentioned in OP.

**Sample Code:-**

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var categoryList = [{"subkey1":"value1"}, {"subkey2" : "value2"}];

var params = {
        TableName : "Movies",
        Key : {
            "yearkey" : 2016,
            "title" : "The Big New Movie 1"
        },
        UpdateExpression : "set #category = :categoryList",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            '#category' : 'category'
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {':categoryList' : categoryList},
        ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW'
    };

console.log("Updating the item...");
docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to update item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("UpdateItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```